Could not create task ':app:copyFlutterAssetsDevDebug'. how to fix?
I cannot start the flutter project in vscode because of this error.
Build file '/Users/xxxx/Desktop/Projects/pfh-agent-app/android/build.gradle' line: 13

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > Could not create task ':app:copyFlutterAssetsDevDebug'.
      > Could not create task ':app:mergeDevDebugAssets'.
         > Cannot use @TaskAction annotation on method IncrementalTask.taskAction$gradle_core() because interface org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.IncrementalTaskInputs is not a valid parameter to an action method.

Not sure how to fix it. I'm using Apple M3 Macbook air.
Restarting vscode, reinstalling flutter
